# compare values from two tables

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables. First one holds the total values of some shopping lists and the second table holds the products in that list. When a shopping list is done the total value is added into the `total` table together with some informations like the list number(`nrList` which is some kind of list id) and the number of products on that list `nrProducts` while the products go into the `listproducts` table.Lets say there are 3 products `tomato,oranges and apples`.They will all share the same `nrList` which,as mentioned before,is something like the list id.

First table `totals`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `totals` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`nrList` int(11) NOT NULL,
`nrProducts` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`total` double NOT NULL,
`data` date DEFAULT NULL,
`ora` time DEFAULT NULL,
`dataora` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`Operator` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`anulat` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
)
```

Second table `listproducts`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `listproducts` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`nrList` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`product` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`quantity` double DEFAULT NULL,
`price` double DEFAULT NULL,
`data` date DEFAULT NULL,
`operator` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`anulat` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Now,i have two things i want to do,they are very similar.
Lets say i have a list with 3 products.In the `totals` table there will be a row with some info and with the `total=10$` `nrProducts=3` and `nrList=1`.In the `listproducts` table i will have 3 rows all having `nrList=1` and each having `price=3$,3$,4$`.
Now,i want the check the following :
1.That if the value of `nrProducts=3` then i have products for that list in the other table.
2.Check if the total in the first table is equal to the sum of the products in the second table.(quantity*price SUM)

I've done some stuff but i don't know what to do next.
I managed to get the number of products for each list from the second table by using this:

```
 SELECT nrList,operator,COUNT(*) as count FROM listproducts GROUP BY nrList
```

But i don't know how to compare if the values are equal without doing two queries.

For the second thing again, I know how to get the sum but i don't know how to compare them without doing two separate queries.

```
SELECT SUM(price*quantity) FROM `listproducts` WHERE nrList='10' and operator like '%x%'
```

I can also do something like what i've done in the other select,this is not the issue.

The issue is that i don't know how to do the things i want in a single select instead of doing two and comparing them.I'm doing this in java so i can compare but i'd like to know if and how i can do this in a single query.

Thanks and sorry for the long post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT totals.nrList,
       IF (totals.nrProducts = t.nrProductsActual, 'yes', 'no') AS matchNrProducts,
       IF (totals.total = t.totalActual, 'yes', 'no') AS matchTotal
  FROM totals INNER JOIN 
      (SELECT nrList,
              COUNT(*) AS nrProductsActual,
              SUM(quantity*price) AS totalActual 
         FROM listproducts 
        GROUP BY nrList) AS t ON totals.nrList = t.nrList
```

Comment: Cool, found out some new stuff thanks to you ! Thanks !